# Time complexity of undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

What will be the Efficient way to find the degree of the specified vertex in an undirected graph (V,E)?

I'm thinking of O(|E|)

Comment: It depends on the representation of the graph. You can design natural representations that take O(|E|), O(|V|), or O(1) time.

Comment: ohh I can use O(|V|) also, that means I'm right with O(|E|) ?

Comment: Without knowing the representation of the graph, we can't answer. I think O(|E|) is the worst complexity for any _reasonable_ representation, but one can definitely come up with representations that are much worse.

Comment: got it thank you